# How should I name my classes and function and even strings?

Tags: python

I am new to Python as you might tell. I have read various documents but I still can not figure out if there's a `"naming best practices"` for **strings functions and of course, classes**.

If I want to name a class or a function as a SiteMap, is it ok to use SiteMap? Should it be Site_map or any other thing, for example?

Thank you!

PS. any further reading resource is GREATLY appreciated!
PS. I am doing web-app development (learning, better to say!)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Naming Conventions:**

There are various Python naming conventions I use. Consistency here is certainly good as it helps to identify what sort of object names point to. I think the conventions I use basically follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

**1)** Module names should be lowercase with underscores instead of spaces.
    (And should be valid module names for importing.)

**2)** Variable names and function/method names should also be lowercase
    with underscores to separate words.

**3)** Class names should be CamelCase (uppercase letter to start with,
    words run together, each starting with an uppercase letter).

**4)** Module constants should be all uppercase.

E.g. You would typically have `module.ClassName.method_name`.

**5)** Module names in CamelCase with a main class name identical to the
    module name are annoying. (e.g. ConfigParser.ConfigParser, which
    should always be spelt `configobj.ConfigObj`.)

**6)** Also, variables, functions, methods and classes which aren't part of your public API, should begin with a single underscore. (using double underscores to make attributes private almost always turns out to be a mistake - especially for testability.)

**Whitespace**

And finally, you should always have whitespace around operators and after punctuation. The exception is default arguments to methods and functions.

E.g. def function(default=argument): and `x = a * b + c`

Comment: Thank you Anas. This is a great explanation for us all. I will do my best to learn and practice these naming conventions by heart. ;-)

Answer (score 18):

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) specifies recommended naming convention for Python. Among rules discussed there, it mentions `underscore_names` for functions and variables (regardless of their type), and `CamelCase` for classes.

Comment: Dear Xion, thank you for this great short to the point response. I wish I could accept two answers as correct ut SO does not allow it. ;-) I am choosing the one below as it's a bit longer yet short so I hope it will be an encouraging read for all who find this thread to learn about these and a bit more than I've asked. Thanks a lot!