# parse and store json data to django model

Tags: json, django, django-models

I am able to call an api within django with requests inside the view to get the data response back in dictionary format as below:

```
{'name': 'John', 'Value': [2, 4, 3]}
```

I am now confused on how to load this data to the mode I have existing:

```
class Table_name(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Can someone please advise?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do this for several views in your app, you should consider using the [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and write serializers to link your JSON structures to your models.

If you don't want that, just put all the conversion logic in your view:

```
def view(request):
    # I assume your JSON data is in a dict called `data`:
    tablename = Table_name(person_name=data['name'],
                           person_value=str(data['Value']))
    if tablename.is_valid():
        tablename.save()
        return ... # response if succeeded
    else:
        return ... # response if failed
```

It is not clear how you want to convert the list in `Value` into a string, so I have just used `str()` in the example above.

Be careful that you may not trust that the API provides you with data formatted as you expect. If so, make sure that generating your dictionary doesn't raise or do anything unexpected, whatever the input data is.

Finally, I recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007811/how-should-i-name-my-classes-and-function-and-even-strings) about how to name your classes (`TableName` would be more commonly accepted than `Table_name`).

Comment: Thank you mimo.. I have to iterate through the json object to get the data into model since I will have around 300k rows.. however this is a once a day activity and I have only one view that will get this data. Can I do something like this?

Comment: `def view(request):
for item in data:
    tablename = Table_name(person_name=item['name'],
                           person_value=str(item['Value']))
    if tablename.is_valid():
        tablename.save()
        return ... # response if succeeded
    else:
        return ... # response if failed`

Comment: or would you advise a better way to push the data into the model instead of every single record. Please advise. Also, I will make sure to read through the naming convention and will follow as advised.