# what is the cause of error in this ? the loop doesnt run continuosly its a menu driven program

Tags: c++

the loop should run in a continuous loop but i can't find the error as it ends on a case 1 after inputting the datas !

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class student
{
public:
    int age = 0;
    string name = "";
};

int main()
{
    bool bistrue = true;

    vector<student> arr;

    while (bistrue)
    {
        cout << "user signup application" << endl
             << "please select an option \n 1.add record \n 2. fetch record \n 3.quit\n";
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        switch (n)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "please enter user name and age\n";
            student temp;
            // cout<<"name\n age";
            cin >> temp.name;
            cin >> temp.age;
            arr.push_back(temp);
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            cout << "enter user id\n";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
            {
                if (i == number)
                {
                    cout << "user name" << arr[i].name << "\n user age" << arr[i].age;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        {
            bistrue = false;
            break;
        }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the "user name" that you input have spaces in it, by any chance?

Comment: Use ```class Student``` not ```class student```

Comment: @MehdiMostafavi Why is that? What's wrong with `student`?

Comment: You issue could be with the non-standard include file `bits/stdc++.h`.  What C++ reference says to use this?

Comment: @cigien It's not wrong but you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119757/are-class-names-allowed-to-be-lower-case

Comment: @MehdiMostafavi Did you notice that the link you shared is for a different language entirely?

Comment: @cigien no difference if you check answers! "By following conventions, others (including us and your instructors, bosses, and co-workers) can better understand and evaluate your code." or check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007958/12244203 for python! You can find for every language :)

Comment: c++ has namespaces, which is the correct fix. There's nothing wrong with `namespace my { class student ...`

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have your `return 0` statement inside the `while` block!

Fixed it!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class student {
public:
    int age = 0;
    string name = "";
};

int main()
{
    bool bistrue = true;

    vector<student> arr;

    while (bistrue) {
        cout << "user signup application" << endl
             << "please select an option \n 1.add record \n 2. fetch record \n 3.quit\n";
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        switch (n) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "please enter user name and age\n";
            student temp;
            // cout<<"name\n age";
            cin >> temp.name;
            cin >> temp.age;
            arr.push_back(temp);
        } break;

        case 2: {
            cout << "enter user id\n";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (i == number) {
                    cout << "user name" << arr[i].name << "\n user age" << arr[i].age;
                    break;
                }
            }

        } break;

        case 3: {
            bistrue = false;

        } break;
        }
    }
    return 0;  // move it outside the while loop
}
```